# Right local path for file download

Tags: jquery, cordova, path, file-transfer

I am using [cordova-plugin-file-transer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/de/index.md) to download a pdf file from a server.

Running that code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var fileTransfer;
var uri;
var fileURL;

// Datei-Bibliothek erst aufrufen, wenn das Device geladen ist.         
function onDeviceReady() {
    fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    uri = encodeURI('http://example.com/file.pdf');
    fileURL = getLocalPath('myNewFile.pdf');
}

getLocalPath = function(file) {
return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/' + file;
};

function openDocument() {

   fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
    },
    false
);
}
```

Gave me the following issue:

> download error source http://example.com/file.pdf index.html:91
>   download error target /www/application/myNewFile.pdf index.html:92
>   upload error code1

I have looked up the error code and it means:

> 1 = FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR

So I think that the app has some trouble to store the file locally. But the local file path should be valid I think... Or am I wrong with that?

my local path the app tries to use:

> /www/application/myNewFile.pdf

The file exists on the server and it is reachable. I have copied the URL and I was able to download the file directly in the browser.

The documentation of [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) suggested to use the following code:

> var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "testImage.png";

But it returns null for me.

Comment: Have you checked that the target location exists on the browser/device ? Also have you made sure you have permission to write to the target location ? For example some versions of Android prohibit applications from writing files outside of their folder.

Comment: I thought that the relative path inside the project itself should be okay ? My browser pushed a message box asking for file permission and I clicked yes. So that should not be the problem.

Comment: refer this https://gist.github.com/dhavaln/2894564 http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/03/09/PhoneGaps-File-API